# JavaFX ComboBox style when focused and item selected

Tags: javafx-8

I have been trying to unstyle a combobox. Basically, I want it fully transparent with only text and arrow showing.
I have managed this by doing:

```
.agent-status-combo .arrow-button, .agent-status-combo .arrow-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, transparent, transparent, transparent;
}
.agent-status-combo, .agent-status-combo:hover, agent-status-combo:focused, .agent-status-combo:showing, .agent-status-combo:selected, .agent-status-combo:filled  {
    -fx-font: 14px "Roboto";
    -fx-background-color: transparent, transparent, transparent, transparent;
}
.agent-status-combo:hover > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, transparent, transparent, transparent;
}
.agent-status-combo .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.agent-status-combo .cell, .agent-status-combo .cell:selected, .agent-status-combo .cell:focused, .agent-status-combo .cell:selected:filled, .agent-status-combo .cell:filled:selected, .agent-status-combo .cell:focused:selected {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, transparent, transparent, transparent; 
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.agent-status-combo .list-cell:selected, .agent-status-combo .list-cell:focused, .agent-status-combo .list-cell:selected:filled, .agent-status-combo .list-cell:filled:selected, .agent-status-combo .list-cell:focused:selected {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, transparent, transparent, transparent; 
}
```

As you can see from the overkill of selectors, I have an issue.
I can't get all this lovely rules to work for when the Combo is focused... It just reverts to default style.

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it not focus traversable solved the problem. True it prevents to use tab to navigate through the UI, but it is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jfoenix.jar` for this purpose.
Simply install it in scene builder and your project also.
Then you can use its components like combo box and all.
After taking combo box to make it transparent you can use following sample code:
    
    `.jfx-combo-box{
        -jfx-focus-color: transparent;
        -jfx-unfocus-color: transparent;
    }
    .jfx-combo-box:focused{
        -fx-background-color: red;
    }
    .jfx-combo-box:selected{
        -fx-background-color: red;
    }`

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to limit 3rd party libraries. Plus I don't really see how this differs from regular css (except maybe the amount of css rules that need to go in).